# Python write() method and close() function not working with latest version of Visual Studio Code. Code works with Python 3.8.5 Shell

Tags: python, windows, file

Awhile ago my friend installed Visual Studio Code (along with the python extension) and it's been great so far until I started learning about File Input and Output. My strings are not saving to the desired .txt file using the write() method and using the close() function at the end. No errors are detected by the computer. The .py and the .txt files are in the same folder. Using the flush() method before the close() function did not work either.

The same code successfully writes to the .txt file with no issues if using the default Python 3.8.5 Shell instead of the latest version of Visual Studio Code. Googling for the issue have yielded no results so far. I'm not even sure what keywords should I be using to look for an answer. I'm using Windows 10 Pro Edition.

```
var_1 = 123
outputFile = open("outputFile.txt", "w")

outputFile.write(str(var_1))

#outputFile.flush() #tried using flush but didn't do anything

outputFile.close()
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that code.  The file is being written to the current directory, which is different for default Python vs. Visual Studio.  You can use this code to print the current directory: `import os; print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: don't use `file.close()`, use **context managers**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention the full path location when you open the file.

Your code will now work.

```
var_1 = 123
outputFile = open(r"C:\....\outputFile.txt", "w")

outputFile.write(str(var_1))

#outputFile.flush() #tried using flush but didn't do anything

outputFile.close()
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I had to put double \\ because it was interpreting it as an escape sequence.

Comment: @TheCorginator, Ok. You can also convert the string to ```raw_string``` and use just a single ```\```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try add the exact address of the file

```
File = open("C:\...\yourfilename","r")
In_file = File.read()
File.close()
```

Visual studio looks for the file in its exe directory

Comment: Thank you it worked! I had to put double \\ because it was interpreting it as an escape sequence.